# Data mining vs Pattern recognition

Tags: artificial-intelligence, data-mining, pattern-recognition

What is the difference between Data mining and Pattern recognition?

Thanks.

Comment: you mine the data and then recognize the pattern?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5026/what-is-the-difference-between-data-mining-statistics-machine-learning-and-ai

Comment: @MitchWheat Nah, that's the sum of Data mining and Pattern recognition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'm going to directly quote the two tags you put on this question:

The *data-mining* tag says:

> Data mining is the process of analyzing large amounts of data in order to find patterns and commonalities.

The *pattern-recognition* tag says:

> Pattern recognition is the term given to the science of automating the
>   classification of input into pre-determined categories, or on the
>   other hand, of being able to recognise particular categories of input
>   by their characteristics.

Now, irony aside, the way I've always seen it is that in data mining you don't necessarily know the patterns.  You have to look for them, which can often involve a lot of hunch-following and guess-work combined with a bit of solid testing.

In pattern-matching, you tend to know the patterns already and you search for them based on their features.

Answer (score 0):

What i think is pattern Recognition is a part of data mining, whenever we talk about data mining we talk in broad sense, it include understanding the large dataset to do particular operation, while patetrn recognition means checking two entity to find a similar pattern/trend